# how to narrow search of youtube videos which belogs to user and have specific words

Tags: youtube-api, gdata

It it possbile to search specific videos uploaded by user?

```
"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="
            + username + "&v=2&alt=jsonc"
```

this request returns all videos which were uploaded by user `username`. How can i search for videos containing word `fire` and is uploaded by user (without videos, which does not containt specified word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube API v2 is deprecated and you should be moving into v3, which provides https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list which I think gives you the possibility of doing what you want.